# Showing full (desktop view) website on devices with particular viewport (e.g. lower than 320px)?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, viewport, meta-tags

I've been finishing my work on a fully responsive website (using Bootstrap 3 framework) and recently the client has asked if it would be possible to have a full (desktop) version of the site on smaller devices (for instance, lower than 320px). Since I've never come across such requirements before, I wonder if there's any legal workaround, e.g. putting an additional viewport meta tag in the head, something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, user-scalable = yes" media="screen and (max-width:      319px)">
```

If there are any known (legal) ways to achieve this (regardless if in JS/jQuery or CSS), I'd appreciate to know your thoughts about this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably have a "Show Desktop Version" button that sets an appropriate cookie and refreshes the page. Then on the server, emit the appropriate viewport meta tag depending on the cookie's value.

Comment: The clients request makes no sense whatsoever. Maybe you should start by asking them why they want to do that.

Comment: Totally agree with you Joonas, since the website is currently looks really fine on all popular devices. The client motivates his request by "what if" statement, saying "What if a customer enters our site with a small old-school device? Let's show him a full desktop version in that case..." Hopefully my PM will manage to change the client's mind.

Comment: When you view a bootstrap site with a browser that doesn't support media queries, the desktop version of the site is shown. There's absolutely no point in crippling the browser experience on purpose for visitors with ancient devices. Just let media queries fail, if they do. [Here's a compatibility chart for media queries.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries). Javascript can be used to extend the support to even older browser versions.

Comment: This is called "Opt Out Responsive Design". I think it's really an odd request (it's mental). There's a lot of information in the comments thread: http://css-tricks.com/user-opt-out-responsive-design/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I had to find a solution for this, since my customer kept on insisting. So I've used a little piece of JavaScript/jQuery in order to change the content of 'viewport' meta. Here it is:

```
var myViewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");

    if ($(window).width() < 320){
    myViewport.setAttribute("content", "width=1024; user-scalable = yes");
    } else {
    myViewport.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0");
}
```

Actually, I have no idea how legal this is, but it works and I've decided to answer my own question, in case any of you guys comes across this weird requirement in future.

Comment: thanks, it works fine on my page http://zinzinzibidi.com/finansal_muhasebe_dersleri/temel_bilgiler