# Web Site Initial View Trouble

Tags: html, css, view

I've a trouble about viewing on my web site. When I visit that page

[This Link](http://zinzinzibidi.com/finansal_muhasebe_dersleri/temel_bilgiler)
It views like this:[image]

I wanna view the pages like this:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

My CSS file here: [style.css](http://zinzinzibidi.com/Areas/finansal_muhasebe_dersleri/Content/css/style.css)

I don't use media screen codes.

Comment: You need the [meta viewport tag(link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn I use this:  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Answer (score 0):

try adding below to your page head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: My code this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

Answer (score 0):

Try `#wrapper { width: 100%; }`  instead of  `#wrapper { width: 760px; }`.  I can see immediate results making that single change in Firebug.

Comment: I can't use that. It ruins the view on desktop.

Comment: Then you can add a max-width to it of 760px.

Answer (score 0):

I found these codes [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214029/showing-full-desktop-view-website-on-devices-with-particular-viewport-e-g-lo)

```
var myViewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");

    if ($(window).width() < 800) {
        myViewport.setAttribute("content", "width=800; user-scalable = yes");
    } else {
        myViewport.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0");
    }
```

It works fine now.